How do you justify energy band bending in an unbiased MOS Capacitor?
Here is a MOS Capacitor:

(Image source: Chapter 5 of Modern Semiconductor Devices for Integrated Circuits by Dr. Chenming Hu)
Now lets consider the idea that the gate voltage is held at 0V, just like the substrate.
From the book "Device Electronics for Integrated Circuits, 3rd edition" (Page 383) by Richard S. Muller, Theodore I. Kamins, Mansun Chan:
"In terms of charge flow, the diagram of  results from the transfer of
holes from the p-type silicon to an ohmic contact (not shown) where the holes are freely
converted into electrons. These electrons are then supplied from the aluminum of the
MOS system."
Here's my attempt of deciphering the above paragraph:

P-type silicon is rich in holes. These holes travel to an "ohmic contact" which really seems to be some form of conductive connection between the gate and the substrate.
These holes are "converted" to electrons in the ohmic contact. (What sense does this make?)
The electrons are supplied from the gate. (Makes sense, the metal/gate has lower fermi level than the silicon, hence easier to pull an electron out from the gate/metal)

If the holes in the substrate, near the interface "travel", then the acceptor atoms must have accepted some electrons.. gaining negative charge.
Therefore, my final question:
So why does the electron band not go up? The immobile negative charges near the interface of the substrate should repel the tiny amount of free electrons in the P-type silicon, increasing their potential energy if they decide to hang out near the interface.

McSuperbX1 - Hi, (a) Thanks for adding the title & edition for the source of some text. Please add the author(s) & page number, to improve that reference to the best of your ability (see the site rule). (b) Where did the image come from? If it's from the same book, please make that clear in the text. Or if it's from a different source, please add a suitable reference for its source. TY

@SamGibson done, thank you for letting me know about the rules.

The work function of the P-silicon body is higher than that of the N+ polysilicon (gate), so when you bring them together under zero bias, electrons will want to move from the gate to the body. Therefore, the electron concentration at the body inferface increases while hole concentrations decrease. That is why the energy band bends down like that.


Relative work functions is a good way to think about this as long as you don't get hung up by the fact that the work function is not a property of the semiconductor as it depends on doping and temperature.

"Therefore, the electron concentration at the body inferface increases while hole concentrations decrease." I understand the increase in electron concentration, but why does that result in downwards bending?

@McSuperbX1 Check the equation (1.8.5) in the link:
https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch1-3.pdf

@internet I'm sorry but can you elaborate further? I dont seem to get it.

@McSuperbX1 The closer the conduction band is to the Fermi level, the higher the electron concentrations. That is what the formula says. In your case above because the electron concentration increases, the conduction band should move closer to the Fermi level; in other words, it bends down.

@internet Yes, perfect! Thank you so much!

At zero bias the Fermi level must be the same at both ends of the structure.
In order to accomplish this there must be bandbending in both the insulator and the semiconductor. The relationship between bands at the interfaces is fixed by the relative electron affinities.
As far as charge is concerned- there is a negative depletion region charge in the lightly doped semiconductor and a positive surface charge on the "metal." If you like you can think of electrons from the "metal" flowing through the wire than connects two ends of the device. These electrons combine with holes to uncover the acceptors and form a depletion region.

The depletion region will consist of negatively charged acceptor ions. Wouldn't this cause the energy band diagram to rise at the Si-SiO2 barrier? I know you said the band bends downwards to equalize the fermi levels.. (which sounds like the real reason), but what's wrong with my analysis?
